# how to set c++11 thread affinity to NUMA node on Windows?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, numa

On Windows, how can I:

- query how many NUMA nodes the system has
- set affinity of an std::thread to the CPU cores of a specific NUMA node?

Comment: So, nobody answers the question? What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

To get the index of the highest node:

```
auto highestnode = 0UL;
GetNumaHighestNodeNumber(&highestnode);
```

To get the affinity of all logical cores on a node for up to 64 total logical cores:

```
auto mask = 0ULL;
GetNumaNodeProcessorMask(nodeindex, &mask);
```

To set thread affinity:

```
SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), mask);
```

Or for greater than 64 total logical cores:

```
auto node = static_cast<PGROUP_AFFINITY>(malloc(sizeof(PGROUP_AFFINITY)));;
GetNumaNodeProcessorMaskEx(nodeindex, node);
```

Where the mask for the node is nodes->Mask.

Large nodes with more than 64 logical cores will be split up into groups specified by nodes->Group.